# Active Directory components appearing on an Exchange Server which is not a Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, windows

Folks, I am having a little -still awkward- issue here.

I have an *HP ProliantDL380p Gen8* server which serves as a *Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V host* for *2 VMs*.

One VM is a *Windows 2012 Server R2 Exchange 2013 Server* and the other one is a *Windows Server 2012 (not R2) Blackberry Enterprise Server* and also a *Domain Controller*.

Both VMs are members of a single domain which consists of another *2 VMs* sitting on another *ProliantDL380p Gen8 server* that are a *Windows Server 2012 R2 File server* and also a *Domain Controller* and a *Windows Server 2008 R2 SQL server*.

Thing is that on *Exchange Server* which is not a DC server i can see AD options like *Users and Computers, Domains and Trusts, Site and Services* etc.

Of course not such a role (AD DS) is installed on the server however i can have access to those settings from this server via *Server Manager*.

The domain also contains another *3 Domain Members (Physical Machines)* with 2 of them *being Windows Server 2003 SP2 Domain Controllers* and the *3rd one being a Windows 2008 Storage Server*.

As you have might figured out we are in the middle of an AD/Exchange migration that will result to have the old servers demoted and removed from the domain.

Also this could be irrelevant but prior to Exchange 2013 installation i have performed an AD preparation using the following command: **.\setup /PrepareAD /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms**.

I may missing something but i wonder do you have any clue on what's going on?

Comment: I modified your question's title to reflect the issue being on an Exchange server to help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server likely had the RSAT tools for ADDS installed at some point.  `"Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-ADDS"` basically.  Probably because the person(s) that installed Exchange ran the AD prep from the Exchange server which requires the RSAT-ADDS tools to run.

Comment: See? That's why i pronounced the word awkward! That was pretty simple, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yeah, technically the ADDS tools aren't required on an Exchange server, you can run the ADPrep on a DC or other computer running the tools already.  But most just tend to install the tools on the Exchange server anyway since you'll often be jumping into ADUC during Exchange admin.